# Dijkstra's Algorithm For a Graph With Only Negative Weights

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

As we know, Dijkstra's Algorithm can't deal with graphs that contain non-negative and negative weights all together.

I was wonder, if we have a graph that contains only negative weights (is a graph like that even exists?), than can we perform Dijkstra on this graph?

Or maybe it will work only with a DAG with all non-positive weights?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be a graph with non-negative edge weights and $-G$ be the corresponding graph where we flip the sign of each edge weight. Then solving for the shortest path problem in $-G$ (what Dijkstra does) is equivalent to solving for the **longest path** in $G$. However, the [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) is know to be NP-hard. Hence either this application of Dijkstra fails (or we have shown P=NP :)).

Answer (score 1):

Even a DAG with all non-positive weights can make Dijkstra fail.

Consider a directed graph with vertices $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ that has three edges $v_1v_2$, $v_1v_3$, and $v_2v_3$ with weights $-1$, $-2$, and $-3$ respectively. If we ask for the shortest path from $v_1$ to $v_3$, Dijkstra will give $-2$ since it finds a (direct) path from $v_1$ to $v_3$. But the actual answer is $-4$; go from $v_1$ to $v_2$ before going to $v_3$.